# Book about a girl who builds a robot who finds out she herself is a robot version of the real her

Tags: story-identification, books

I read this book about five years ago. The cover of the book was green and I feel like it had an eye on it or something; an unnaturally green eye.

The main character was a girl and she built a robot that looks exactly like her. Then she realised that she herself is a robot, built by the real her. So there are 3 of them?

I think one of them dies in a ditch or something? Something about the boot/trunk of a car.

Comment: Can you remember anything else about this? Why does each of them build the robot them? What happens when she finds out? Can you remember anything about one of them dying other than what you've got? Anything about the boot of the car? Can you remember any of the plot at all? If you remember anything else at all please [edit] your question to include those details. Remember the more you include the more likely it is that someone will find this for you.

Answer (score 7):

This sounds like it might be a slightly twisted memory of ["Robot Girl"](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/24986865-robot-girl) (2015) by Malorie Blackman. I can't quite find all the information available on the book but from reading various reviews I have found the following:

- Her father invents the robot which is based on Claire, the main character.
- Claire is horrified about this creation and wants to destroy it.
- The creation is squishy to the touch and she is firm to the touch i.e. she's likely a robot and the creation is a human; though this isn't clearly spelled out in any review, only hinted at and they mention a twist a the end.

The review below mentioned most of the points above and then there is these from [Fantasy Book Review](https://www.fantasybookreview.co.uk/Malorie-Blackman/Robot-Girl.html) and [Anne Harding Training](http://www.anneharding.net/malorie-blackman-robot-girl.html) that also have some helpful information.

> Claire is excited and she's nagging her mother to tell her what her father has been doing in his laboratory, but her mother is no wiser than she is and tells Claire that she will simply have to wait until her father is ready to show her what he's been doing. He's a famous inventor and Claire knows that whatever it is will be exciting. For now all she can do is to tell her pen friend - and be patient.
>
> But Claire is in for a shock. When she sees the 'invention' she knows that her father has created a monster. It's a robot and her father has modelled the robot on Claire, even down to using her thought processes: the only difference is that Claire has a firm body but the robot's body is, well, squishy to the touch. Claire's mother isn't entirely certain about AI-E (as the robot's called) - but Claire wants it destroyed. She's deeply upset, particularly with her father doesn't understand why she's upset. Her only outlet is to write to her pen friend, Maisie. Maisie's sympathetic to a certain extent, but points out that Claire is only upset with her father because of AI-E, whilst SHE is upset because her father only wants to make money out of her.
>
> It's a brilliant story and you're going to have to be prepared to reverse all your thinking as you read as nothing, but nothing, is quite what you first think it to be.
>
> <sub>[The Bookbag, Robot Girl by Malorie Blackman](http://www.thebookbag.co.uk/reviews/Robot_Girl_by_Malorie_Blackman)</sub>

The book's cover also seems to match your memory, it has green elements and is a close up on the face of one of the girls showing her very green eyes.

[image: The book's cover, described above]

---

Found with the Google query `book girl makes robot of herself`.

Comment: Seems to be a great match, except it looks like the girl's eyes are brown with a green reflection of a humanoid figure.

Comment: this is quite helpful, thank you. I had heard of this book before and dismissed it because I thought the title wouldn't be so blatantly obvious. But I'll give it a read and hope that it's the book! Thanks